# Can disable-output-escaping be set using a template parameter?

Tags: xslt-1.0

Why won't the following work in XSLT1.0?

```
<xsl:template name="GenerateSummaryOld">
  <xsl:param name="Content" />
  <xsl:param name="Length" />
  <xsl:param name="DisableOutputEscaping" />

  <xsl:value-of select="substring($Content, 1, $Length)" disable-output-escaping="$DisableOutputEscaping" />
  <xsl:if test="string-length($Content) &gt; $Length"><i>...text has been shortened</i></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm using the following when calling the template:

```
<xsl:with-param name="DisableOutputEscaping">no</xsl:with-param>
```

I'm trying this in a SharePoint Content Query WebPart but I get a web part error.  If I hard-code disable-output-escaping as "yes" or "no" in the template, i get no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation was provided in the good answer by C. M. Sperberg-McQueen.

Here is a workaround:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAmp">&amp;</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="vYesNo" select="'yes'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$vYesNo = 'yes'">
      <xsl:value-of select="$vAmp" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$vYesNo = 'no'">
      <xsl:value-of select="$vAmp" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the result is:**

```
&
```

**If we replace**:

```
 <xsl:variable name="vYesNo" select="'yes'"/>
```

**with**:

```
 <xsl:variable name="vYesNo" select="'no'"/>
```

**the result of the modified transformation now is**:

```
&amp;
```

Comment: This is the solution I had to use.  It just does sit right with me that I need 8 lines of code when I should be able to do it in 1.  Oh well.  Thanx.

Comment: @jeshort2, You are welcome. DOE is not encouraged and in fact it isn't mandatory XSLT feature and some XSLT processors don't implement DOE. Usually we say that very few things, if any can't be done without DOE, but maybe your case is different.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**  the value of `disable-output-escaping` must be specified literally in the XSLT stylesheet; it cannot be calculated at stylesheet execution time.

That is, the behavior you are observing is the behavior prescribed by the language definition.

**Longer answer:**  The [XSLT 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template) shows the syntax of `xsl:value-of` like this (more or less):

```
  <!-- Category: instruction -->
  <xsl:value-of
       select = string-expression
       disable-output-escaping = "yes" | "no" />
```

Note that "string-expression" is italicized here; it means that the `select` attribute has as its value not the string "`string-expression`" but any XPath expression which can be evaluated and coerced to a string.  But the "yes" and "no" of `disable-output-escaping` are not italicized, not described as being an expression, and not described as being an attribute-value template.  The "yes" or "no" value must be given literally.

The closest the spec comes to saying this explicitly (that I could find) is the note in section 7.6.2 on attribute value templates:

> **NOTE:**Not all attributes are interpreted as attribute value templates. Attributes whose value is an expression or pattern, attributes of top-level elements and attributes that refer to named XSLT objects are not interpreted as attribute value templates. ...

This is one of a number of early-binding constraints in XSLT designed to ensure that stylesheets could be compiled and not just interpreted.

Comment: I figured the value had to be hard-coded, but I could not find any definitive answer.  Thank you.